# Cant find Jquery UI dependencies using Bower, Jquery UI, and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs, bower

I am using Jquery UI, Bower, and RequireJS in a project and am having difficulty configuring Jquery UI with Require.  Basically Jquery UI is trying to find its dependencies in the root directory, and not where they are located, giving me an error.

I understand as of 1.11 Jquery UI supports AMD and the documentation notes that it works with a directory like so:

```
    ├── index.html
    ├── js
    │   ├── app.js
    │   ├── jquery-ui
    │   │   ├── accordion.js
    │   │   ├── autocomplete.js
    │   │   ├── button.js
    │   │   ├── core.js
    │   │   ├── datepicker.js
    │   │   ├── dialog.js
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── jquery.js
    │   └── require.js
```

However, using Bower, the directory is more like

```
    ├── index.html
    ├── js
    │   ├── app.js
    |── bower_componenents
    │   ├── jquery-ui
    │   │   ├── accordion.js
    │   │   ├── autocomplete.js
    │   │   ├── button.js
    │   │   ├── core.js
    │   │   ├── datepicker.js
    │   │   ├── dialog.js
    │   ├── jquery
    │   │   ├── jquery.js
    │   └── require 
    │   │   ├── require.js
```

How does one configure Require so that Jquery UI can find its dependencies?

Comment: Did you find how to ? I am trying to solve the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just setting it up wrong.  I got it working after changing my config file to

```
    require.config({

    shim: {

        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },

        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },

        backboneLocalstorage: {
            deps: ['backbone'],
            exports: 'Store'
        },

    paths: {

        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        'jquery-ui': '../bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui',
        underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        backboneLocalstorage: '../bower_components/backbone.localStorage/backbone.localStorage',
        moment: '../bower_components/moment/moment',
        text: '../bower_components/requirejs-text/text'
    }
});



require(['backbone', 'views/app-view', 'routers/router'],

    function   (Backbone, AppView, Workspace  ) {

        new Workspace();
        Backbone.history.start();       
        new AppView();  

});
```

and then defining in my backbone view like so

```
    define([
    'collections/todos-collection',
    'views/todo-view',
    'common',
    'backbone',
    'jquery',
    'jquery-ui'

], function(Todos, TodoView, Common, Backbone, $){
```

As you can see, jquery-ui will attach itself to the $ symbol.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it partially working by aliasing bower_components with the path attribute in the requirejs config. But the internal jquery libs are assuming that all of the javascript files are lumped together in the same directory structure (relative references) so it still doesn't work.

I'm considering using Grunt to copy my dependencies under my js directory so that everything is on the same baseUrl. Not exactly ideal, but it would probably make it easier to use r.js or gulp later on.